# How can I use 2 TP4056 to safely discharge 2 18650 cells in series

Tags: lithium-ion, protection, lipo, tp4056, over-discharge

I am new to electronics. I have made a robotic car type thing with `arduino` and `L298N` and I want to power it using two 18650 cells in series. I have watched videos on `youtube` where guys use 2 18650 cells in series without any over-discharge protection board (e.g. TP4056 ). But I don't think it is safe and I think there should be over discharge protection circuit (e.g. TP4056). I don't know how to do that with two 18650 cells. Should I connect two 18650 cells with two TP4056 and connect TP4056 in series and use it across load?
Is is safe? What is the proper way to use two 18650 cells with over discharge protection?
below screen shot shows what I am thinking of donig.

**Edit : I am not worried about charging. I have different charger for that.**

[image]

Thank you

Comment: TP4056 is a charger ic, not battery protection. You might be thinking of a DW01.

Comment: I am talking about those protection module using tp4056 . one of these https://www.amazon.com/TP4056/s?k=TP4056

Comment: You should use "protection modules" that does **NOT** have a TP4056 included. In your current circuit, if you use the TP4056 to charge the batteries there is a chance that you will **SHORT CIRCUIT** one of the batteries (unless you use two separate, isolated 5 V supplies). It is much simpler to just not have that TP4056 there as it is designed for **single cell** designs, not two cells in series like yours.

Comment: I will not charge the battries through same circuit. i have different charger to charge the, sorry if my question is confusing. that is why i pasted a picture. My intention is to just use battries across load.I have edited my question . Thanks

Comment: *I will not charge the battries through same circuit* Then there is no reason that the TP4056 is needed as it is a charger IC. Get some DW01 modules instead!

Comment: okay can i use 18650s in series without any protection circuit? i am charging these separately.

Comment: Do you intend to connect the batteries to the TP4056's permanently, or remove them when charging?

Comment: A complete circuit diagram  of what you intend will help. | A TP4056 will stop charging when a cell is fully charged BUT will not discharge an overcharged cell. It is not suited to use as a BMS. IF you are charging the cells one at a time or both at once  with isolated power sources then you can use 2 X TP4056 to control charging.

Comment: @BruceAbbott Sir I will remove them when charging. Once they are charged then i will connect them to my load aka motors. I just want a mechanism to prevent over discharge. that is why i am using tp4056 module because i read that it has over discharge protection. Thank you

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Sir I do not intend to charge with tp4056. I just want to use them across load, I just want to prevent over discharge.

Comment: The TP4056 WILL provide over discharge protection if used as shown.